# Create a JSON from JSONPath in Javascript

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am new to Javascript world and need some clarification on JSONPath.
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

I understand JSONPath is used to parse the JSON structure and get specific values.
My question is, Is it possible to reverse this behavior?
For example, Suppose I show the list of 'books' in a 'store', as given in the article, in a table/grid and I have a 'Create' button when clicked, gets the input of 'category', 'author', 'title', 'isbn' and 'price'. Now I know the JSONPaths for these input elements. Is it possible to create a JSON structure with the JSONPaths given? Are there any tools to do this?
Or Am I just missing something basic?

Regards
BK

Comment: Stand here with the same problem. Everyone implement features to read from JSON with a given JSONPath, but no one cares about creating JSON from a JSONPath. Articles like this have no answers to solve the problem. Unfortunately i found nothing to do it in Javascript, but these PHP-Library does the job: https://github.com/Skyscanner/JsonPath-PHP You just create a new Object and set your values by a given JSONPath: $obj = new JsonObject(); $obj->set($path, $value); Then create an output and done. Maybe you can do it with PHP or using the functionality as example to build your own Javascriptsolut